# 3-column grid breaking after certain point

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I have a WP blog with a theme based on F5 (Reverie). Currently using a child theme for handling the custom styles, etc.

In addition, I'm using Infinite Scroll (part of JetPack plugin) to manage pagination on home and archived pages.

**The issue**
It looks fine on the initial loading of the first set of posts (set to 6). When I click the button to trigger infinite scroll, six more load (still looks fine). Load another and the 3-column grid starts to break (lose the float). At first I thought it might be the images using for the post. I even tried deactivating some plugins I thought could be an issue; no luck.

I have also tried adjusting the css (height, min-max) of the posts to see if helps. No go.

home.php

```
<div class="row" id="content-home">
    <div class="small-12 columns" id="content" role="main">
        <h5 style="margin-left:15px;">Latest Posts</h5>
        <?php query_posts('offset=1'); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

content.php

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('index-card small-12 large-4 columns'); ?>>
<header>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail('large'); } ?></a>        
</header>
<div class="entry-content">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php bvblog_small_meta(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like I ran out of character. the code for the last block should be `<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('index-card small-12 large-4 columns'); ?>>
 <header>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail('large'); } ?></a>  
 </header>
 <div class="entry-content">
  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <?php bvblog_small_meta(); ?>
 </div>
</article>`

Answer (score 0):

```
.row .small-12.columns#content article {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left !important;
    min-height: 540px;
}
```